# View BinData in MongoDB as text

Tags: mongodb, bindata

In MongoDB I have row with field name is ***content*** as BinData type,
I want to view the content of this fields as text, does MongoDB support that in mongoshell.
My row content:

```
{
"_id" : "adsdadad9809kjsa-",
"fetchInterval" : NumberInt("2592000"),
"fetchTime" : NumberLong("1534691840163"),
"markers" : {
    "_updmrk_" : "1532099830-1713101603",
    "dist" : "1",
    "_gnmrk_" : null,
    "_ftcmrk_" : null,
    "__prsmrk__" : null
},
"metadata" : {
    "CharEncodingForConversion" : BinData(0,"dXRmLTg="),
    "OriginalCharEncoding" : BinData(0,"dXRmLTg="),
    "_rs_" : BinData(0,"AAABVg=="),
    "_csh_" : BinData(0,"AAAAAA==")
},
"retriesSinceFetch" : NumberInt("0"),
"score" : 0,
"status" : NumberInt("2"),
"batchId" : "1532099830-1713101603",
"content" : BinData(0,"CjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPgo8aHRtbCBsYW5nPSJ2aS12biI+IAo8aGVhZD4gCjx0aXRsZT5UaOG7sWMgcGjhuqltIGLhu5Ugc3VuZyAtIFJvbmcgYmnhu4NuIGjhu691IGPGoSBjYW8gY+G6pXAgSXZlbmV0IEJlYmUsIDJnPC90aXRsZT4gIAo8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOCIvPgo8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiIgY29udGVudD0iU+G6o24gcGjhuqltIDM2OTI3LCAgUm9uZyBiaeG7g24gaOG7r3UgY8ahIGNhbyBj4bqlcCBJdmVuZXQgQmViZSBsw6Agc+G6o24gcGjhuqltIGN1bmcgY+G6pXAgQ2FueGkgZ2nDunAgeMawxqFuZyB2w6AgcsSDbmcgcGjDoXQgdHJp4buDbiwgYuG7lSBzdW5nIERIQSBjaG8gbsOjbyBi4buZIGPhu6dhIHRy4bq7Ii8+PG1ldGEgbmFtZT0ia2V5d29yZHMiIGNvbnRlbnQ9IlRo4buxYyBwaOG6qW0gYuG7lSBzdW5nLFJvbmcgYmnhu4NuLGjhu691IGPGoSxJdmVuZXQgQmViZSwgQsOhbmggxINuIGThurdtLCBT4buvYSwgdGjhu7FjIHBo4bqpbSwgQsOpIMSDbiIvPgo8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJtc3ZhbGlkYXRlLjAxIiBjb250ZW50PSIwRTU5NkU4QjJGMzczQTlEQTc4NEEzNEUyRDQ0ODNGMSIvPgo8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJnZW8ucmVnaW9uIiBjb250ZW50PSJWTi1I4buTIENow60gTWluaCIvPgo8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJyb2JvdHMiIGNvbnRlbnQ9ImluZGV4LGZvbGxvdyxub29kcCIvPgo8bWV0YSBuYW1lPSJSQVRJTkciIGNvbnRlbnQ9IkdFTkVSQUwiLz4KPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0ibGFuZ3VhZ2UiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InZpZXRuYW1lc2UiLz4KPG1ldGEgbmFtZT0iUkVWSVNJVC1BRlRFUiIgY29udGVudD0iMSBEQVlTIi8+CjxtZXRhIHByb3BlcnR5PSJmYjphcHBfaWQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9IjE0OTkxMjEzNzY5NzM0MzIiLz4KPG1ldGEgcHJvcGVydHk9Im9nOnRpdGxlIiBjb250ZW50PSJUaOG7sWMgcGjhuqltIGLhu5Ugc3VuZyAtIFJvbmcgYmnhu4NuIGjhu691IGPGoSBjYW8gY+G6pXAgSXZlbmV0IEJlYmUsIDJnIi8+CjxtZXRhIHByb3BlcnR5PSJvZzp0eXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJwcm9kdWN0Ii8+CjxtZXRhIHByb3BlcnR5PSJvZzppbWFnZSIgY29udGVudD0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jb25jdW5nLmNvbS8yMDE4LzA2LzM2OTI3LTQwNTYxLWxhcmdlL3RodWMtcGhhbS1iby1zdW5nLXJvbmctYmllbi1odXUtY28tY2FvLWNhcC1pdmVuZXQtYmViZS0yZy5qcGciLz4KPG1ldGEgcHJvcGVydHk9Im9nOmRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIiBjb250ZW50PSIgUm9uZyBiaeG7g24gaOG7r3UgY8ahIGNhbyBj4bqlcCBJdmVuZXQgQmViZSBsw6Agc+G6o24gcGjhuqltIGN1bmcgY+G6pXAgQ2FueGkgZ2nDunAgeMawxqFuZyB2w6AgcsSDbmcgcGjDoXQgdHJp4buDbiwgYuG7lSBzdW5nIERIQSBjaG8gbsOjbyBi4buZIGPhu6dhIHRy4bq7LCBNw6Mgc+G6o24gcGjhuqltIDM2OTI3ICIvPgoJPG1ldGEgcHJvcGVydHk9Im9nOnNpdGVfbmFtZSIgY29udGVudD0iQ29uY3VuZy5jb20iLz4JCQoJPG1ldGEgcHJvcGVydHk9Im9nOnVybCIgY29udGVudD0iaHR0cDovL2NvbmN1bmcuY29tL2JhbmgtYW4tZGFtL3RodWMtcGhhbS1iby1zdW5nLXJvbmctYmllbi1odXUtY28tY2FvLWNhcC1pdmVuZXQtYmViZS0yZy0zNjkyNy5odG1sIi8+CQo8bGluayByZWw9ImFsdGVybmF0ZSIgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jb25jdW5nLmNvbS9iYW5oLWFuLWRhbS90aHVjLXBoYW0tYm8tc3VuZy1yb25nLWJpZW4taHV1LWNvLWNhby1jYXAtaXZlbmV0LWJlYmUtMmctMzY5MjcuaHRtbCIvPgo8bGluayByZWw9Imljb24iIHR5cGU9ImltYWdlL3ZuZC5taWNyb3NvZnQuaWNvbiIgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jb25jdW5nLmNvbS9pbWcvY29uY3VuZy5pY28iLz4KPGxpbmsgcmVsPSJzaG9ydGN1dCBpY29uIiB0eXBlPSJpbWFnZS94LWljb24iIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vY29uY3VuZy5jb20vaW1nL2NvbmN1bmcuaWNvIi8+CQo8bGluayByZWw9InB1Ymxpc2hlciIgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9wbHVzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vK0NvbmN1bmciLz4KPGxpbmsgaHJlZj0iL3RoZW1lcy9jb25jdW5nMy4wL2Nzcy9tYWdpY3pvb21wb
),
"contentType" : "text/html",
"signature" : BinData(0,"Ld8g8QEimAbqFoBt9Za9Yw==")
```

}

Does any way to show the value of content as text?

Comment: It is already showing as base64 encoded text. What are you asking really?

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz
I mean I need it show as text without encoded (decode).
example:
```base64 encoded text: 4dfs453fdss
text decode: hello```

Comment: It is binary data. If you are asking "dXRmLTg=" then it is "utf-8". Others mostly contain non-printable characters (and also char(0)).

Comment: Yes, Can we decode binary data become human text that we can understand?
@cetinBasoz

Comment: No, I am saying they are not human readable text but binary data. I don't know for "content" because it was cut off and not decoded to check.

Comment: _csh_ for example decodes to 4 chars which are all char(0).

Comment: Thanks @cetinBasoz
I found the way how to read this data https://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: In mongo shell you should be able to use atob(), btoa() for conversion.